# Is this the first report that acetonitrile & propionitrile crystals create highly polar nano surfaces? How does one detect or quantify such surfaces?

Tags: crystal-structure, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

Phys.org's [Titan-in-a-glass experiments hint at mineral makeup of Saturn moon](https://phys.org/news/2021-08-titan-in-a-glass-hint-mineral-makeup-saturn.html) says:

> Titan, Saturn's largest moon, is a natural laboratory to study the origins of life. Like Earth, Titan has a dense atmosphere and seasonal weather cycles, but the chemical and mineralogical makeup are significantly different. Now, earthbound researchers have recreated the moon's conditions in small glass cylinders, revealing fundamental properties of two organic molecules that are believed to exist as minerals on Titan.
>
> **The researchers will present their results today (~August 26, 2021) at the fall meeting of the American Chemical Society (ACS).**
>
> "Simple organic molecules that are liquid on Earth are typically solid icy mineral crystals on Titan because of its extremely low temperatures, down to -290 F," says Tomče Runčevski, Ph.D., the project's principal investigator. **"We found that two of the molecules likely to be abundant on Titan—acetonitrile (ACN) and propionitrile (PCN)—occur predominantly in one crystalline form that creates highly polar nano surfaces, which could serve as templates for the self-assembly of other molecules of prebiotic interest."**

**Question:** Is this the first report that [acetonitrile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetonitrile) and [propionitrile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propionitrile) crystals create highly polar nano surfaces? How does one detect or quantify such a surface?

Comment: Nice, up to here "... , which could serve as templates for the self-assembly of other molecules of prebiotic interest." where they switch to unnecessary bullshittry. Ouch, embarassing.

Comment: Very true! They had to insert nano somehow.

Comment: I had exactly the same thought as @Karl! The templating stuff is so they can push a case for building blocks of life getting a start, etc.

Comment: Indeed. What they've found might be highly interesting astronomically speaking but not so much generally and chemically

Comment: Pure nonsense "high polar nano surfaces" to serve as templates of what! These people have no clue to what life is...they are blindly wandering.

Comment: @M.Farooq if there's a way to express that in "science words" it may make for a great answer.

Comment: @uhoh, This will open a floodgate of spam and comments. Life is not defined, nor people (read biologists) know anything about it despite all their claims of understanding evolution. Nobody can create even single bacterium from scratch or even an atom. This is beyond human means.

Comment: @M.Farooq the part about bacterium may be true today but folks are working hard to do exactly that.